# How to customize a lens of pst-optic with the following requirement?

Tags: pstricks, pst-optic

The following code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-optic}
\begin{document}
\lens
[
    nameF=F2,
    nameFi=F1,
    spotO=270,
    focus=4,
    OA=-3,
    AB=1,
]
\end{document}
```

produces the following output.

[image]

### Objectives

I want to

- add `$F_1$`, `$2F_1$`, `$F_2$` and `$2F_2$`,
- draw the image `A'B'`,
- the three extended lines to `B'` are dashed instead of solid.

[image]

How to do so?